# What is the difference between these two recursive functions?

Tags: recursion, scheme

The problem is to find the nth power of x^n of a number x, where n i s a positive integer. What is the difference between the two pieces of code below. They both produce the same result.

This is the code for the first one:

```
(define (power x n)
  (define (square n) (* n n))
  (cond ((= n 1) x)
        ((even? n)
         (square (power x (/ n 2))))
        (else 
         (* (power x (- n 1)) x))))
```

This is the second one:

```
(define (power x n)
  (if (= n 1)
      x 
      (* x (power (- n 1) x))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is in the time it takes for the two algorithms to run.

The second one is the simpler, but also less efficient: it requires `O(n)` multiplications to calculate `x^n`.

The first one is called the *square-and-multiply* algorithm. Essentially, it uses the binary representation of the exponent, and uses the identities

```
x^(ab) = ((x^a)^b)
x^(a+b) = (x^a)(x^b)
```

to calculate the result. It needs only `O(log n)` multiplications to calculate the result.

Wikipedia has some [detailed analysis of this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).